# Is it feasable for a developer to build and integrate the back-end of a website with another developer's front-end code?

Tags: php, html, css, frontend, backend

Background:
I am a member of a start-up company, and we are now about to start building the company's website from mock-ups which we've already designed. The original plan was for me to build the front-end of the website, and when it is finished, we would hire a back-end developer to study my code and build and integrate the back-end.

Question:
If I build the front-end myself, would a back-end developer be able to build the back-end and integrate the two? Or would that be too difficult/time-consuming, and the back-end developer would prefer to build the front-end from scratch himself? (rendering my time spent on building the front-end useless)

Thank you

Comment: Considering right now I'm working on the back-end of a new live chat system while another developer concentrates on the front-end, I'd say it's quite possible!

Comment: If you put forward good programming practices and have all of your code organized and commented, the backend developer will have no problem integrating them together.

Comment: for me it would depend on a LOT of things.

Comment: If you do a proper handover of your code, explaining what the back-end needs to actually do to integrate with your front end, and it helps if this is also properly documented; then there shouldn't be any problems: back-end and front-end developers are often different people

Comment: If the backend has been well tought out in te sence of code seperation. Its no problem. I just had the same thing where anotger dev made the htm css and js. I did the backend and used twig templates. So it was basically copy pasting his stuff to the roght place and putting some variables in.

Comment: Just as long as the right hand knows what the left hand is doing; plus, if you're going to be using forms, remember to "name" your form elements, and if using a DB, to ask your back-end developer if he/she is using prepared statements, up-to-date password storage methods, etc. There are many other things at play here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you keep the variables consistent along the way, there should be no issues whatsoever.  As long as you trust what the frontend developer has done, you should be good to go.  The only situation I can see being an issue is if the frontend dev had some backend components directly modifying the source, but that's rare and bad practice considering how database oriented these systems usually are.

I say do an in-depth analysis before you dive in.  If it looks too complicated you might look favorably at designing the frontend yourself.  Either way, good luck!

Comment: Thank you all for your answers - it appears that the ultimate answer is that it is feasable!